# Why Rails "link_to" does not work for delete action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

In `index.html.erb` I display all products, and next to each product I have `Edit` and `Delete` actions:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  ...
  <%= link_to("Edit", edit_product_path(product.id), :class => 'action') %>
  <%= link_to("Delete", product, :method => :delete, :class => 'action') %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

The `Edit` link works ok. However, the `Delete` link does not work. I get the following error:

```
Unknown action
The action 'show' could not be found for ProductsController
```

I guess it is because the request method is GET rather than DELETE. But, I don't know why this happens if I set explicitly `:method => :delete`.

`routes.rb` is pretty simple:

```
root :to => "products#index"
resources :products
```

I have Javascript enabled.

Please suggest.

Comment: Did you try adding the show action, even though you are not using it so that your routes have you covered?... Just a thought

Comment: Do you have delete action in your controller? And also try rake:route command to see if delete path is defined properly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do you have `rails.js` specified in a `javascript_include_tag`? This is required for the unobtrusive `DELETE` method to work. If you're using jQuery then there's a [solution for that too.](http://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs)

Comment: In the page source I see that `rails.js` is loaded. I do use jQuery 1.4.4. Is this a problem ? I just downloaded it from the official site and put it in `javascript_include_tag`. Should I replace it with files from your link ? What exactly should I download ?

Comment: @Misha: Download the rails.js file in the src directory and put it into your public/javascripts folder as rails.js. If you're using jQuery, you *must* replace the Prototype `rails.js` with the jQuery equivalent.

Comment: @Ryan: Thanks a lot for guiding me! If I use jQuery rather than Prototype, do I still need `javascript_include_tag :defaults` ?

Comment: I removed `javascript_include_tag :defaults` and put `javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.4.4.min.js', 'rails.js'` instead (the new `rails.js`, from the link above). The error is still the same: `The action 'show' could not be found for ProductsController`. What else could be wrong ?

Comment: @Misha: You can change the defaults using this in _config/application.rb_ `config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:default] = ["jquery", "rails"]`

Comment: @Ryan: Nice! So, you say to change the defaults and remove `javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.4.4.min.js', 'rails.js'`, right ? But, how Rails will know which jQuery file/version to use ?

Comment: The problem was with the `rails.js` file that I downloaded. I downloaded some HTML file instead and called it `rails.js`. So stupid... Now everything works fine. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 5):

Dont forget to include `jquery_ujs` in your `application.js` file:

```
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

It needs to be `product_path(product)` instead of `product` in your delete link.

Comment: What does the resulting HTML look like for the link tag?

Comment: `<a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" class="action" href="/products/73">Delete</a>`

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem - actually I had changed my old 'delete' action to 'destroy' - but forgot If your using SSL.. (e.g ssl_required :destroy)