# Deleting friendships

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Been trying to solve this for quite some time but can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I am simply trying to destroy a friendship between two users.

The view looks like this:

#### friendships/index.html.erb

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>

<% if user.id != current_user.id %> 
<%=h user.name %> 
<%if current_user.is_friend? user %>
<%= link_to "Destroy", friendships_path(:friend_id => user), :method => :delete %> 

<%else%>
<%= link_to "Add friend", friendships_path(:friend_id => user), :method => :post %> 
<% end %>
 <% end %>

<% end %>
```

#### friendship controller

```
    def index
      @users = User.all
    end

    def show
     @user = current_user
    end

 def create
   @friendship = current_user.friendships.build(:friend_id => params[:friend_id])
   if @friendship.save
     flash[:notice] = "Added friend."
     redirect_to root_url
   else
     flash[:error] = "Error occurred when adding friend."
     redirect_to root_url
   end
 end

def destroy
  @friendship = current_user.friendships.find(params[:id])
  @friendship.destroy
  flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed friendship."
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

I am getting this error:

> No route matches [DELETE] "/friendships"

I But it looks like I have the path when I run rake routes:

```
     friendship GET    /friendships/:id(.:format)         friendships#show
                PUT    /friendships/:id(.:format)         friendships#update
                DELETE /friendships/:id(.:format)         friendships#destroy
```

Comment: looks like you id isn't making it to the link. What if you replace `friendships_path(:friend_id => user)` with `"/friendships/#{user.id}"`?

Comment: also: what is a friendship? A relation between two users? The id from the user surely can't be the friendship id can it?

Comment: looks like this is a duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446697/why-rails-link-to-does-not-work-for-delete-action

Comment: That's true froderik. The friendship has: an id, user_id and a friend_id.

If I try what you suggest above I will destroy the friendship with id=user.id. This is not really what I am looking for, I need something that will find my friendship with the parameter friend_id=user.id

Thanks for your input though, I manage to delete something but it wasn't completely right.

Comment: Not really the same problem. That one is requesting a GET method and has a lot to do with JAVASCRIPT. No Javascript in this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
<%= link_to "Destroy", friendships_path(:friend_id => user), :method => :delete %>
```

should looks like

```
<%= link_to "Destroy", friendship_path(friendship), :method => :delete %>
```

(singular, not plural form)

The `friendship` is an instance of Friendship object, the way to get it depends on the model code. Most likely, something like

```
<%= link_to "Destroy", friendship_path(current_user.friendships.find_by_friend_id(user)), :method => :delete %>
```

should work.

Comment: Thank you so much!
I tweaked the second suggestion to:
<%= link_to "Destroy", friendship_path(current_user.friendships.find_by_friend_id(user.id)), :method => :delete %>
And it worked!