# <%= posts_delete_path %> dont work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, posts

I'm programming a website with a friend, and I'm getting one error with my code. In the computer of my friend, he have the same code and don't have any error.

I get the following error:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.

Well, we're newbie in Rails and I get this error when I try to load the posts page. We think the error is on deleting a post, because if we comment the line of "posts_delete_path", everything works. For delete a post, we are using:

show.hmtl.erb:

```
<% @hashtag.posts.each do |p| %>
    <li>Posted by: <%= p.user.name %></li>
    <li>Content:</li>
    <li><%= p.content %></li>
    <li><a href="<%= posts_delete_path %>/<%= p.id %>" >Delete</a></li>
<% end %>
```

routes:

```
   match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
   match 'posts/delete/:id', to: 'posts#destroy'
   resources :posts, :only => [:create, :show]
```

posts controller:

```
def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    if current_user.id == @post.user_id
       @post.destroy
    end
end
```

---- edit ----
rake routes:

```
      posts GET    /posts(.:format)           posts#index
            POST   /posts(.:format)           posts#create
   new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)       posts#new
  edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)  posts#edit
       post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)       posts#show
            PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)       posts#update
            DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)       posts#destroy
```

We know that's the newbie way to delete a post, but we don't find any better solution. (If you want suggest something, we will be glad too).

Comment: Well, I don't know, just can't delete the posts, instead delete the posts, I see the posts. (instead "delete" method, I get "post" method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone who tried help me. Now I solved my problem, but by other way.

What I do is:

In view:

```
<% if current_user.id == p.user_id %>
            <%= button_to "Delete", { :controller => :posts, :action => 'destroy', :id => p.id }, :method => :delete %>
<% end %>
```

In controller:

```
  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    #if current_user.id == @post.user_id
       @post.destroy
    end
  end
```

In routes:

```
resources :posts
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `link_to` notation like this:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", p, method: :delete %>
```

Also, you should try to stop users from even seeing the delete button in the view, something like:

```
<% if current_user == p.user %>
    <%= link_to "Delete", p, method: :delete %>
<% end %>
```

This will only show the delete link only to the owner of the post.

Also like Ganesh said , turn this:

```
match 'posts/delete/:id', to: 'posts#destroy'
resources :posts, :only => [:create, :show]
```

to:

```
resources :posts, :only => [:create, :show, :destroy]
```

Checkout the routing system in the rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html, and see which of the routes you will need.

Comment: Thanks Zippie, but when I do the modifications that you told to me, when I click in the link "Delete", I'm redirected to "http://localhost:3000/posts/12".  Can help?

Comment: ahhh, try this: resources `:posts, :only => [:create, :show, :destroy]` or just make the `resources :posts`

Comment: Don't work again :/  I search for "link_to rails" on Google and I open the APIDOC of this. Look what I found: "Supported verbs are :post, :delete and :put. Note that if the user has JavaScript disabled, the request will fall back to using GET. "

What's JavaScript they're talking? Because the described error is the same I have here.

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446697/why-rails-link-to-does-not-work-for-delete-action

Comment: Sure, and thanks for trying to help me. I edited the question, see above the routes.

Comment: Thanks @Zippie, but I can't destroy posts yet. The rails.js of this link works for Coffee Script? (sorry, I really don't know about Javascript / jQuery / Coffee)

Comment: Now is working, I changed link_to to button_to and it's works! Thanks for everyone.

Comment: cool, glad it worked and that you solved the problem on your own.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to "Delete", p, method: :delete %>
```

and modify the `routes.rb` with

> resources :posts

Comment: Thanks Ganesh, but don't work for me :( When I click in the link (when server is on) "Delete" I'm redirected to "localhost:3000/posts/12";. Can help?

Comment: once check using, <%= link_to "Delete", posts_delete(p) %>

Comment: Just get the error: "Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 181ms" in console and see "We're sorry, but something went wrong." on http://localhost:3000/hashtags/4 (where posts is "stored")

Comment: can you bpost the screenshoot of rake routes

Comment: Updated the question, see the routes above. :)

Comment: Now is working, I changed link_to to button_to and it's works! Thanks for everyone.

Comment: Sorry Ganesh, but that isn't exactly what solved my problem. Anyway, thanks for help me! :)

Answer (score 0):

looks like ur link is fine, but sounds like you did not **include your js**, thats why it is redirecting you to the show page when you click delete.

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', product, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

#### 1. Check your `/assets/application.js`

for `//= require jquery` and
`//= require jquery_ujs`

Add in application.js this code

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

#### 2. Check your /layouts/application.html.erb

for `<%= javascript_include_tag "application"%>`

```
<head>
    <title>My awesome app</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application"%>
    <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
  </head>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I don't understand the first step Francois, can you explain? Just copy and paste this code into my project or need change something? When I do by the first way, I get "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

Below the code of the first step I have:
"window.<# ProjectName #> = {
 ...
}

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 ...
}

Comment: I solved the problem, just pasted your code below my code. But I still can't delete the posts, I'm redirected to "show", instead use the "delete" method, use the "post"(or "get", I don't know) method. Do you know what's problem?

Comment: Just a little thing, I don't know anything about jQuery / JavaScript, but for what I know, we use Coffee in our project. This changes something? @Francois

Comment: try removing the `window.Instablah` and `window.fbAsyncInit` so the file starts with `// This is a manifest fil` and try again see what happends?

Comment: Well, any part of my project work, because need be logged in to do things. Just a thing, I don't need the "rails.js" in my project?

Comment: Are you running rails3? Check your layouts if you have `<%= javascript_include_tag "application "%>` in the head

Comment: Now is working, I changed link_to to button_to and it's works! Thanks for everyone.

Comment: Hi @francois, you can see the answer above (it's my own answer) or here: <%= button_to "Delete", { :controller => :posts, :action => 'destroy', :id => p.id }, :method => :delete %>